# Частица НЕ с причастиями при противопоставлении

Tags: частица-не, частица

Как писать частицу с причастиями в случае противопоставления?
Везде приводятся примеры, в которых сначала идет не+причастие, а потом — противопоставление ему. А если противопоставление сформулировать наоборот?
— Написанный от руки, но *не+напечатанный* текст;
— Треснутая, но *не+разбитая* ваза";
— Надетая, но *не+прикрученная* крышка.
В таком случае надо писать слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

**Конструкции с союзом НО называют сопоставительными или уступительными,** в них называются разные признаки, которые обычно **не сопутствуют** друг другу.

Например: **Дом небольшой, но уютный. Речка небольшая, но быстрая.** Это утверждение  несопоставимого признака.

**Участок красивый, но не большой (среднего размера).** Это отрицание ожидаемого (желаемого)  признака. Слитное написание тоже возможно: красивый, но небольшой (маленький). Выбор делается по смыслу. (Авторский выбор — это особенность конструкций с союзом НО).

Обратим внимание на то, что сравниваются **признаки из разных тем,** в то время как при противопоставлении это признаки одного характера: **Дом не большой,  а маленький.**

А что у вас?  **У вас приведены придуманные примеры, коммуникативная функция которых неясна.**

1) Вот два признака: **ненапечатанный и написанный.** В каком отношении они могут находиться? Обычно  ненапечатанным произведением называют то, что так и не было напечатано, например: Г-жа N прочтет **ненапечатанный** рассказ Ф. Сологуба «Венчанная». При раздельном написании обязательно добавлено **наречие**: Этот стих, к тому времени **еще нигде не напечатанный**, вызвал удивленные аплодисменты.

Поэтому верным является сочетание: **написанный от руки, но еще  не напечатанный текст.** Если временное наречие отсутствует, то противопоставление теряет смысл: ненапечатанный текст это и есть рукописный текст.

2) С вазой еще хуже. Эта ваза **или треснутая, или разбитая**, в двух состояниях она находиться не может.

3) Единственный пример из реальной жизни — это крышки. Стерилизовать банки нужно **с надетыми, но не прикрученными**  крышками. Кстати, здесь тоже авторский выбор, любой вариант годится (отрицание или утверждение).

**И вывод:** не надо придумывать предложения и сочетания, так как работать с ними не имеет смысла. Берите примеры из существующих текстов, там коммуникативность будет всегда на месте.

Comment: Итак. "Стерилизовать банки нужно с надетыми, но не прикрученными крышками." Вы написали частицу "не" раздельно с причастием. Почему?

Comment: Можно написать слитно, если Вам так больше нравится, я говорила в ответе об авторском выборе. Это смысловое решение, отрицание действия. В конструкция с союзом НО выбор по смыслу возможен.